# Is there a paper that formalizes questions from a mathematical perspective?

Tags: logic, reference-request

Is there a paper or text that formalizes what a question is, from a mathematical perspective? I am sure there has been some work on this topic. I would be very interested in work on the logic of questions.

Comment: The term "erotetic logic" may be relevant.

Comment: See also [the SEP article on "Questions"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/questions/).

Comment: Yanjing Wang's work: [How to reason about what/why/how](https://fh.pku.edu.cn/docs/2019-04/20190410160416944665.pdf) may be relevant here

Comment: J.Hintikka, [The Semantics of Questions and the Questions of Semantics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Semantics_of_Questions_and_the_Quest/0M8NAQAAIAAJ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that, per the comments above, the answer is definitely **yes**. Indeed, a quick glance suggests that there is a fair amount of work on the topic which cannot be summarized in an MSE-fitting answer. However, I can mention a couple good starting sources:

- The [Stanford Encyclopedia article "Questions"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/questions/) has a lot on the topic as usual *(and more broadly the term "[erotetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erotetics) logic" is also a fruitfully searchable phrase)*.
- Wisniewski has a book [*The posing of questions*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-015-8406-7) in the Synthese library which seems very on topic.

So that's a freely-available survey article with a rich bibliography, a key term, and a monograph in a respected book series - probably a decent starting point!